# Linux multiple page bounds and cpu segments

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am puzzled as to how Linux is able to have so many segments and it can still have bounds checking. To my knowledge, modern CPUs have a couple of segment data registers (code, data, etc).

But Linux has multiple segments of its own: Stack, BSS, heap, code, globals, and many more (especially if the heap is large and composed of many segments). Not every CPU has enough registers to track all these segments.

If I am not mistaken, Linux stores each segment in a separate page, so how is it able to prevent one of these pages from reading or writing out of bounds?

My only possible explanations are that Linux:

1. performs some manual checking on every write
2. places all the pages close together in a way such that they can be tracked with a few registers

Comment: you can also ask your question in this forum: https://unix.stackexchange.com. it may help more.

Comment: It’s not the OS doing this. It’s the hardware. OS just tells it what is allowed and what isn’t. To put it simply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the advent of 64-bit Intel, the concept of hardware segments has died the death that should have taken place in the 1970's.

> But Linux has multiple segments of its own: Stack, BSS, heap, code, globals, and many more (especially if the heap is large and composed of many segments).

These are pedagogical concepts that have little relationship to reality outside the implementation of linkers--but which bad books on operating systems persist in using.

A stack is just memory. Heap is just memory. The operating system has no knowledge if memory is being used for a stack whether it is being used for a heap. The operating system simply allocates memory to a process with different attributes (e.g., read/write, read only, read/execute). What the process does with that memory is its own business.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer user3344003; but could you please also explain how those attribute rules are enforced? For example, to prevent the process from writing to read only memory, does the CPU have some sort of check before write, or does the OS do this?

Comment: These days, they use page protection for that.